# number of inserted documents using bulk insert

Tags: php, mongodb

Could you please tell if it's possible to get number of inserted documents using bulk deleted?
For some, reason batchInsert it always returns:
array
  'err' => null
  'n' => int 0
  'ok' => float 1

The code is something like this using mongodb shanty:

```
$result = Model_Mongodb::insertBatch($importData, array('safe' => true));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, MongoDB doesn't return the number of documents inserted by an insert operation. This is a known issue -- please see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4381, and vote for the issue if this is important for your use case.

However, I will note that if you are using `insertBatch` with safe mode and you do not get an error result, you may assume that all the documents were inserted successfully.

**EDIT** (to answer questions from comments):

1. By default, a bulk insert stops if there is an error (and returns the error information in the return result). You can override this behavior in MongoDB 2.0+ with the `continueOnError` flag, in which case the return result will only give information about the last error; any earlier errors will not be reported.
2. No, you cannot do a bulk upsert. To do an upsert (create if missing, otherwise update), you must use the `update` method with the `upsert` flag set to true.
3. That ticket is not strictly about `batchInsert`, no -- all `insert` commands currently return n==0 in the `getLastError` result.

Comment: What if some subscirbers were inserted, but some not?

Comment: Is it possible to use batch insert using autoupdate as well, for example, if such document exists, it would update it?

Comment: But it looks like update returns correct number, not zero all time as insert, right?

Comment: Right. The bug has been fixed for updates some time ago, but not yet for inserts.

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer might be a little bit late - but who knows, it could help someone.

I found a hack-ish way of getting the number of inserted documents, it goes like that:

1- Count documents.
2- BatchInsert()...
3- Count documents again.
4- subtract results from step 3 with step 1

Of course, to re-use this method effectively, I had to put in a function, which added a little bit of complexity.

The benefits of this function is it returns the *actual* number of inserted documents, that eliminates removed duplicated documents(using `ensureIndex` and `dropDups`) and un-inserted documents due to errors , etc...

Here's the code::

```
/**
 * A hack for batchInsert() function to count inserted documents.
 * PHP 5.3+ is required for callback functions.  

 * @param MongoDBCollection $collection
 * @param  callable $batchInsertFunction The actual batchInsert code.
 * @return int Number of inserted documents.
 */
 function countedBatchInsert($collection, $batchInsertFunction)
{
    //Count current documents (before inserting)
    $countDocuments['before'] = $collection->count();

    //Execute batchInsert
    $batchInsertFunction();

    //Count documents again.
    $countDocuments['after'] = $collection->count();

    //Simple arithmetic operation to determine the number of inserted documents.
    return $countDocuments['after'] - $countDocuments['before'];

}
```

Here's an example :

```
/*Example*/

//Specify collection.
$collection = $this->myDatbase->myCollection;
//Data to batchInsert
$batchData = /*Array of stuff*/
//Create callback function.
$batchInsertFunction = function() use ($collection, $batchData)
{
    //Do the actual batchInsert
    $collection->batchInsert($batchData, $myOptions);
}
//call countBatchInsert().
countBatchInsert($collection, $batchInsertFunction);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem it returns number of records that have been batch inserted, right? It looks like it's possible that between 2 calles of counting documents some other documents could be inserted by other user, besides our batch inserting.

Comment: @Oleg Considering how fast batch insert usually is, I don't think this is an issue. BTW: You might be getting issues because in the sample code; I passed `$collection` variable to batchInsert function instead of data to insert, it's fixed now.